# How to. Connect to facebook through IOS with my custom User Interface

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm very new to Facebook connect and Facebook API. I'm a little bit lost with the different flavours of Facebook features. Is it possible to connect to facebook without having any of the existing facebook UI. I wanna to access the facebook features through a game and wanna to be able to send an image to my friends on facebook. I have my own user interface, everything from login to sending a message should be handled in "background".
Can some indicate to me a good tutorial to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create your own custom UI in the game, although you might want to use some FB motives and color schemes to indicate Facebook integration.

**Getting Started:**

A nice way to install the Facebook SDK is via [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/).

**Overview:**

At its core Facebook provides a JSON-based interface to their system secured using OAuth. OAuth allows an app to authenticate for a period of time after using an access token - this is a revokable token that is assigned after successful username password based authentication.

If you wanted you could invoke the JSON API directly after authenticating with an OAuth2 provider. However, the Facebook SDK builds on top of this for you by providing:

- An (fairly) quick and easy way to authenticate to Facebook without getting into the nitty-gritty of oauth.
- The Facebook Graph API - an interface for performing common functions.
- The Facebook Query Language (FQL) API - an interface that provides some more power.

There are lots of tutorials on the Facebook site itself. You can get the tutorials/sample apps from here:

```
    git clone https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.5-howtos.git
```

**Summary:**

- Yes you can provide your own UI and do (most) of the work in the background. The Facebook Graph API dispatches some events on the main thread, but for the purpose of your app you probably won't notice this.
- Go through the tutorials and sample apps for iOS, provided by Facebook.
- Ask a more specific question about authentication or posting data.